# How to used external class as target for NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, selector, nstimer, target

I have a Swift class i want to re-use for button animations.

```
//
//  ButtonAnimation.swift

import Foundation
import UIKit


@objc class ButtonAnimation : NSObject {

    let animationButtion :UIButton!
    let animationLastStep : Int
    let animationStepIncrement : Int
    let timer : NSTimer
    let baseName : String
    var animationStep: Int


    required init?(animationTimer: NSTimer) {

        self.timer = animationTimer
        let configuration: [String : AnyObject] = self.timer.userInfo as! [String : AnyObject]

        self.animationButtion =  configuration["Button"] as! UIButton
        self.animationLastStep = configuration["stop"] as! Int
        self.animationStep = configuration["start"] as! Int
        self.baseName = configuration["basefilename"] as! String

        if (self.animationLastStep > self.animationStep) {
            self.animationStepIncrement = 1
        } else { self.animationStepIncrement = -1 }

    }


    @objc
    func animateButton() {

        self.animationStep += self.animationStepIncrement

        if (self.animationStep == self.animationLastStep) {
            self.timer.invalidate()
        }

        print("image \(self.baseName)\(String(format:"%02i",self.animationStep))")

        if let image = UIImage(named: String(self.baseName ) + String(format:"%02i",self.animationStep)) {
            self.animationButtion.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        }

    }

}
```

This class is used from the viewController and invoked by the

```
    let dictionary: [String : AnyObject] = ["Button" : sortOnSeverityButton,
                                            "start": 0,
                                            "stop": 20,
                                            "basefilename": severityButtonAnimBasename]

    severityButtonTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(severityButtonTimeInterval, target: ButtonAnimation.self , selector: #selector(ButtonAnimation.animateButton), userInfo: dictionary, repeats: true)
```

There are no errors when compiling the code, but gives an exception when executing the code starting the animation.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '+[homecaremonitor.ButtonAnimation animateButton]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to class 0x103353c30'

If i am interpreting the exception correct, there is something not right with the selector. But i am out of ideas how to resolve this.

Any help is appreciated !
Peter

I now changed the invocation

```
        let buttonAnimation :ButtonAnimation = ButtonAnimation()

        severityButtonTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeButtonTimeInterval, target: buttonAnimation , selector: #selector(ButtonAnimation.self.animateButton), userInfo: dictionary, repeats: true)
```

And moved the code initially in the initializer to the func animateButton

```
    if (self.timer == nil) {

        self.timer = animationTimer
            let configuration: [String : AnyObject] = self.timer.userInfo as! [String : AnyObject]
                self.animationButton =  configuration["Button"] as! UIButton
                self.animationLastStep = configuration["stop"] as! Int
                self.animationStep = configuration["start"] as! Int
                self.baseName = configuration["basefilename"] as! String

                if (self.animationLastStep > self.animationStep) {
                    self.animationStepIncrement = 1
                } else { self.animationStepIncrement = -1 }

        self.startValue = self.animationStep

    }
```

It bugs me that i have to create an instance before creating the timer. When calling self as a Target, the NSTimer instance is passed to the initializer. When i want to use an external class this seems not to be possible. Therefore i have to create an initializer in the function called by the Selector.

Comment: You're passing the class instead of an instance of the class

Comment: Added the code changes i made. This is the neatest possible option ? Or are there better ways to code this ?